# How well is JWST doing on maintaining its Halo orbit?

Tags: james-webb-telescope, halo-orbit

I looked around a little bit online but did not find anything discussing how well JWST is doing with managing its orbit. I was wondering if there were any surprises or issues.

It's been out there almost 2 years now and the flight folks should have a good idea if their planning was on target and if fuel will last even longer than originally calculated. (Of course, the great launch and L2 insertion were a large help to fuel conservation.)

Comment: I’m pretty sure it’s actually been out there 2 years now, launch was in late 2021. A year ago they mentioned 20 rather than 10 years of fuel, but I also don’t see anything more recent

Comment: You can view the orbit in 3D using my scripts here: https://space.stackexchange.com/a/57832/38535 The JWST trajectory data on Horizons was last updated 2024-Jan-17 https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/api/horizons.api?format=text&MAKE_EPHEM=NO&COMMAND=jwst

Comment: @fyrepenguin oops... seems I cannot count!

Comment: @fyrepenguin I'm pretty sure I heard something a couple of months ago saying things are going much better than originally expected and now they expect a longer operational lifetime.

Comment: @Barmar I believe the thing that went so well was their initial injection was pretty much exactly on target, as perfect as it could possibly be, so they didn't have to burn a bunch of fuel fixing the orbit and that means they had nearly twice the expected (i.e. minimum acceptable) amount left after reaching their station.

Comment: @DarthPseudonym yes, that's what I heard.

Comment: @Barmar Yes, that’s what I referred to about 20 rather than 10 of fuel, but there were articles about that within a month or two of launch. Didn’t see updates after that

Answer (score 11):

Only partial:

Not directly answering since it seems ok:

Can only find up to 2022:

> Orbit around L2 is maintained through regular station-keeping burns, which are scheduled every three
> weeks. As of July 12, 2022, there have been four station-keeping burns, with typical durations of tens of
> seconds. During commissioning, three station-keeping burns were skipped because the computed
> correction was negligibly small.
>
> Predicted lifetime of consumables
>
> There are no consumable cryogens onboard JWST; the telescope and the science instruments are passively
> cooled by the sunshield and radiators, and MIRI’s active cryocooler recycles its helium. The only onboard
> consumables are propellant: fuel and oxidizer. Before launch, JWST was required to carry propellant for
> at least 10.5 years of mission lifetime. Now that JWST is in orbit around L2, it is clear that the remaining
> propellant will last for more than 20 years of mission lifetime. This fortunate surfeit has multiple causes:
> an accurate launch; launch on a day that required relatively less energy to get to L2 than most other
> possible launch dates; three timely and accurate mid-course corrections that sent JWST to L2 with the minimum possible propellant usage; and finally, careful stewardship of mass margins by the engineering
> team over the years, such that the remaining mass margin was used to add more propellant than required,
> until the tanks were full.
> For the remainder of the mission, propellant will be used for two purposes: stationkeeping burns (using
> fuel and oxidizer) to maintain the orbit around L2, and momentum dumps (using only fuel) to remove
> momentum from the reaction wheels. Momentum accumulates as solar photons hit the sunshield and
> impart a net torque, which the reaction wheels resist by spinning up. The actual rate at which the
> observatory builds up momentum is within specifications and is well below worst-case allocations, which
> further contributes to propellant lifetime. While the detailed propellant usage depends on orientation,
> which is set by the observing schedule, the big picture is that JWST has sufficient propellant onboard to
> support science operations for more than 20 years.
>
> Projected observatory lifetime
>
> At this point, it is not clear what will determine the duration of JWST’s mission. The mirrors and
> sunshield are expected to slowly degrade from micrometeoroid impacts; the detectors are expected to
> experience cumulative slow damage from charged particles; the sunshield and multilayer insulation will
> degrade from space weathering; the spacecraft was designed for a five year mission (as is standard for
> NASA science missions); and the science instruments include many moving parts at cryogenic
> temperatures. These sources of degradation were all taken into account in the design of JWST, with
> performance margins set so that JWST will still perform after many years of operation. At present, the
> largest source of uncertainty is long term effects of micrometeoroid impacts that slowly degrade the
> primary mirror.
>
> The single micrometeorite impact that occurred between
> 22—24 May 2022 UT exceeded prelaunch expectations of damage for a single micrometeoroid ,
> triggering further investigation and modeling by the JWST Project. The Project is actively working this
> issue to ensure a long, productive science mission with JWST.

> July 12 2022
>
> Characterization of JWST science performance from commissioning

Also, one of the sensors abnormality has to be accounted for:

> Mid-Infrared Instrument Operations Update
>
> On Apr. 21, 2023, the James Webb Space Telescope team shared that one of the MIRI (Mid-Infrared Instrument) observing modes, called Medium-Resolution Spectroscopy (MRS), showed a reduction in the amount of light registered by MIRI’s detectors. Initial analysis of MIRI’s imaging mode did not show a similar effect. However, as part of the team’s investigation into the issue, additional monitoring observations were taken with MIRI imaging. Combined with earlier data, these new calibrations have revealed a reduced signal for MIRI imaging at the longer wavelengths.
>
> This change does not substantially impact MIRI’s science capabilities but will have an impact on the exposure times needed for MIRI imaging.
>
> There is no risk to the instrument, and the effect on imaging is less than the effect in MRS. The team is investigating the cause of this issue.

https://blogs.nasa.gov/webb/

Upto 2024 observing schedule:

https://www.stsci.edu/jwst/science-execution/observing-schedules